# Column from other two columns in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

I have a mongodb collection with records similar to this one...

```
{
   id:'8345344',
   x:'-33.2315',
   y:'-53.53453'
}
```

I need to query my database but query fields that are a composition of the other ones.
For example...

```
{
   id:'8345344',
   x:'-33.2315',
   y:'-53.53453',
   newField:['-33.2315', '-53.53453'] //Values of x and y of this record
}
```

This field should only be used for querying, it should not be saved.

I saw something about $project and aggregation in mongodb but from what I've read I don't think it will suit my needs.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) but it's not as straight forward as you might think:

```js
db.combine.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 1,
        "tag": { "$cond": [ true, [ "x", "y" ], 0 ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$tag" },
    { "$project": {
        "newField": { "$cond": [ 
            { "$eq": [ "$tag", "x" ] },
            "$x",
            "$y"
        ]}
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "newField": { "$push": "$newField" }
    }}
])
```

With MongoDB 2.6 there is a new [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) operator that removes the obscure usage of [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) in that first project phase

```js
db.combine.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 1,
        "tag": { "$literal": [ "x", "y" ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$tag" },
    { "$project": {
        "newField": { "$cond": [ 
            { "$eq": [ "$tag", "x" ] },
            "$x",
            "$y"
        ]}
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "newField": { "$push": "$newField" }
    }}
])
```

The [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) actually sort of explains why you need this sort of process and cannot just define a "newField" as an array by itself, as the content is "literally" defined and does not substitute variables.

So while you cannot just substitute the values from other fields as elements you can play in this way.

Of course there is even a simpler way to do this with MongoDB 2.6 and up, using the [**`$setUnion`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operator:

```js
db.combine.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "x": { "$push": "$x" },
        "y": { "$push": "$y" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "newField": { "$setUnion": [ "$y", "$x" ] }
    }}
])
```

So first that forms both the "x" and "y" fields as arrays in themselves then uses [**`$setUnion`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) to **merge** those contents into a single array, as that operator takes multiple arrays as it's arguments.

The catch here is I wouldn't rely on the ordering as this is considered not to "strictly" be an "array" and from the mouth of the CTO, "a set is not considered to be ordered in any way"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually avoided the need of this by solving some other problem I had. So I won't use this now, but I do find your answer really useful and will try just for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: @lascort In any of the forms it should be useful as a technique in general. In your specific case it is possibly redundant as you can easily access each field and place them in that way in post processing.

Comment: That's what I meant, it should be useful for me (and hopefully for others) anyway. I wanted to do this in order to use mongo's `$near`, but I ended up doing it "the math way".

Comment: @lascort Okay, but just to clarify, you won't be able to use the `$near` or any other geo-spatial functions in this way. They need to be actual values in a collection document and they need to be indexed with a geospatial index. There are now "geo" pipeline stages for aggregate, but they need to be the **first** stage. So projection will not work for you. You need to modify your actual data.